# Use one set method for multiple properties MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class, oop, setter

I have several properties that use essentially the same `set` method:

```
classdef MyClass

    properties
        A
        B
    end

    methods

        function mc = MyClass(a,b)   % Constructor
            mc.A = a;
            mc.B = b;
        end

        function mc = set.A(mc, a) % setter for A
            if a > 5
                mc.A = a;
            else
                error('A should be larger than 5');
            end
        end

        function mc = set.B(mc, b) %setter for B
            if b > 5
                mc.B = b;
            else
                error('B should be larger than 5');
            end
        end


    end


end
```

1. Is there a way to use only one `set` function for variables `A` and `B`? (Please note that the `error` function use the property names as strings.)
2. Is it suggested to use only one `set` function? What are the possible drawbacks of using one `set` function?

Comment: I'm not at all an expert on MATLAB's OOP but it seems like this isn't doable. You could create a helper method that they both call to cut down on the Copy+Paste though.

Comment: Thanks @excaza. Could you elaborate more on the helper method? A link perhaps?

Comment: @BarisErkus I agree this likely isn't possible with MATLAB OOP, as @excaza says. I think his suggestion was just to use multiple `set` methods but put the body in a separate function (e.g., a static method in the same class) to cut down on the boilerplate. If this isn't clear I can post an example...

Answer (score 1):

The only real way is to extract the common code to another function, and call it from the setters:

```
classdef MyClass

properties
    A
    B
end%public properties

methods

    function mc = MyClass(a,b)   % Constructor
        mc.A = a;
        mc.B = b;
    end

    function mc = set.A(mc, value) % setter for A
        mc = mc.commonSetter(value, 'A');
    end

    function mc = set.B(mc, value) %setter for B
        mc = mc.commonSetter(value, 'B');
    end


end%public methods

methods(protected = true)

    function mc = commonSetter(mc, property, value)
        if value <= 5;
            error([property ' should be less than 5');
        end
        mc.(property) = value;

    end%commonSetter()

end%protected methods


end%classdef
```