# How do I write a common set method for multiple properties in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, oop, setter

I work within a project which has several classes which define properties that use essentially the same  set method. To make the code more readable, I want to implement a `commonSetter` method. The overall goal is to include this `commonSetter` method in the superclass, so that all the classes could use it.

The question was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655150/use-one-set-method-for-multiple-properties-matlab), but unfortunately, the answer is not working. I changed the code to the following, but get the error: Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached.

```
classdef MyClass

properties
    A
    B
end

methods
    
    function mc = MyClass(a,b) % Constructor
        mc.A = a;
        mc.B = b;
    end
    
    function mc = set.A(mc, value) % setter for A
        mc = mc.commonSetter(value, 'A');
    end
    
    function mc = set.B(mc, value) % setter for B
        mc = mc.commonSetter(value, 'B');
    end
    
    
end

methods(Access = protected)
    
    function mc = commonSetter(mc, value, property)
        % do some stuff
        disp('Made it into the commonSetter!')
        mc.(property) = value;
    end
end 
end
```

So far I know that there is an infinite loop where `mc.(property) = value;` calls `set.A` (or `set.B`), which in turn calls `commonSetter`.
In [my post @ MathWorks](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/787619-how-do-i-write-a-common-set-method-for-multiple-properties?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_view#comment_1431969) the following was suggested:

> To break that loop I guess you should look at `builtin()` and `subsasgn()`. Maybe [Overriding `subsref` and `subsasgn` - effect on private properties](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16652-overriding-subsref-and-subsasgn-effect-on-private-properties?s_tid=srchtitle) can be of some help.

Currently, I have troubles realizing the suggestions and additionally not very comfortable to overwrite `subsasgn()` as I'm not sure how it will affect the overall project. I would like to know, if someone has other ideas or knows how to overwrite `subsasgn()` safely.

Comment: What does `commonSetter` need to do - is it basically just some input validation?

Comment: In the minimum example it suppost to set the value for the given property for e.g. MyClass('A',2) or MyClass('B', 3).

Comment: OK but in that case you wouldn't need a setter method at all - I have a workaround in mind but I wanted to check whether it would meet the requirements. I'll write it up as an answer anyway...

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking forward to your answer

Comment: Do note that you don't need setters at all. If you don't define the `set.A` method, you can still set the `A` property. Overriding `subsasgn` is fairly trivial too, as you can call the "builtin" function after checking/adjusting the inputs. The MATLAB documentation has some really good examples for this.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the recursion error, you could just let the `commonSetter` method output the new value instead of the object.

```
classdef MyClass

    properties
        A
        B
    end

    methods

        function mc = MyClass(a, b)% Constructor
            mc.A = a;
            mc.B = b;
        end

        function mc = set.A(mc, value)% setter for A
            mc.A = mc.commonSetter(value, 'A'); % update mc.A
        end

        function mc = set.B(mc, value)% setter for B
            mc.B = mc.commonSetter(value, 'B');
        end

    end

    methods (Access = protected)

        function new_value = commonSetter(mc, value, property) % only return the new value
            % do some stuff
            disp('Made it into the commonSetter!')
            if value > 5
                new_value = -10;
            else
                new_value = value;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the recursion problem!

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest.